# Lightning Email Template Deploy: How do I get the Lightning Email Template Folder Id?

Tags: lightning-experience, deployment, email-template, folder

I have Lightning Email Templates that I need to deploy to 13 orgs, and rather than recreate them manually in each org I've extracted them with Data Loader, and now I need the Public FolderIds from each org to upload them to. When I do an extract of all Folders, I can't see the Lightning ones (Private or Public) - it lists only the Classic Email folders and it also doesn't look like the Document Folders are related to this.

Other than creating a dummy template and then extracting that to find the folder id, is there not an easier way?

I noticed that it also does not give an option to link to a Lightning Letterhead, which I have to manually go in and add afterwards. I might as well copy/paste in every org as it seems more work to do all the work around using DataLoader...Is the Lightning Email Template really so hard to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

Our product Snapshot on the AppExchange migrates both classic and lightning email templates no problem. I am the CTO at Metazoa we build that product.

Answer (score 0):

Ive spent a couple of days on this. Not giving up yet though. I finally found out how to retrieve them at least.

I used this sfdx command:
sfdx project retrieve start --metadata EmailTemplate:/

Beyond this I cam stuck on how to get them deployed to the higher orgs. I know they have 2 parts - the .email file and the .flexipage file. When i try to deploy via Copado i get this error: *You don't have the right to create Lightning pages of type EmailTemplatePage.* According to SF documentation, these aren't deployable OR retrievable. But i retrieved. So I'm hoping I can find a way to deploy too.

Also - when i retrieved I saw a -meta file come over with the .email file. I put them in a folder so the template folder just came over too but that one doesn't have an associated -meta file like the other classic email template folders have.

Does normal change sets work?